# Load on Heroku Instance seen in heroku run top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cedar

When I run `heroku run top` on my server I see a very high load, currently 36.37

I realise this is probably not the dyno that runs the app, but it does seem very high to me, does this explain poor performance in heroku from time to time?

Additionally, where in the architecture is heroku running my command?

Any insight would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `heroku run top` will not run it on the same dyno as your app is running.  That will be run in a one-off dyno - something that contains your same code and environment.  For more, see:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps